# Partial specialization for/on template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization, template-templates

I'd appreciate help partially specializing a template (`Manufacturer`) for template template parameters? Here's my current (unsuccessful) attempt.

```
#include <iostream>

enum FORMAT{ A , B };

template<typename D , FORMAT F>
struct Manufacturer
{
    Manufacturer(){ std::cout << "Generic" << std::endl; }
};

template<
        template<FORMAT> class D , FORMAT F
        >
struct Manufacturer<D<F>,F> : Manufacturer<void,F>
{
    Manufacturer(){ std::cout << "Specialization" << std::endl; }
};

template<FORMAT F>
struct Device : Manufacturer<Device,F>
{
};

int main()
{
    Device<A> device;
}
```

Comment: [Yes](http://ideone.com/cDVpGu)?

Comment: @KerrekSB I've edited my question.

Comment: Look at you compiler messages (or try another compiler): error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list. Change it to `struct Device : Manufacturer<Device<F>,F>`

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks. I thought KerrekSB was making a fuss about my language.

Comment: BTW, why on earth would `Manufacturer<Device<F>,F>` match the specialization? I thought surely `Device<F>` is a type and not a template.

Comment: The base template takes a type and specializations cannot change that.  What the specialization is saying is "when this type looks like this, use this class/template instead".  If the base template takes a type, you must always give it a type, hence the `Device<F>` and not the `Device`

Comment: @GuyGreer ah ... So its just a sort of pattern matching *a la* Haskell.

Comment: @SirGuy post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as such.